# calculate sse2 instructions in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, sse

I am running linpack benchmark with -O3 and msse2 options. I want to calculate the total number of SIMD instruction produced in the assembly file. Is there any way to automate the process OR I have to lookup for each instruction defined in SSE2 instruction set? There are a lot of pointers to SSE2 instructions (eg xmm registers but their count can be double than the actual SSE2 instructions). Sample Assembly code.

```
.L12:
movss    -4(%rcx), %xmm1
addq    $16, %rax
addq    $16, %rcx
mulss    %xmm0, %xmm1
addss    -20(%rax), %xmm1
movss    %xmm1, -20(%rax)
movss    -16(%rcx), %xmm1
mulss    %xmm0, %xmm1
addss    -16(%rax), %xmm1
movss    %xmm1, -16(%rax)
movss    -12(%rcx), %xmm1
mulss    %xmm0, %xmm1
addss    -12(%rax), %xmm1
movss    %xmm1, -12(%rax)
movss    -8(%rcx), %xmm1
mulss    %xmm0, %xmm1
addss    -8(%rax), %xmm1
movss    %xmm1, -8(%rax)
cmpq    %rdx, %rax
jne    .L12
rep ret
.cfi_endproc
```

Comment: `grep -c xmm`? counting only lines with a reference to xmm-register. Or objdump -S file.o and grepping the sse instruction opcode prefix?

Comment: Do you want to count instructions like `movnti r32, m32`, which [requires SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Added_with_SSE2) but doesn't use any XMM regs?  Same for `PAUSE`, `MFENCE`, prefetches, and probably some others.  Also, if you want to count how many SSE/FPU instructions *run*, use performance counters.  10 insns outside a loop is less than one instruction in a loop that runs 1000 times.  If you really do just want to know what you asked, Aki's suggestion to count lines matching the `%xmm` pattern is pretty solid, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to count only those instructions that use xmm registers.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen `grep -c 'xmm' filename` is what worked for me. You can add it as an answer

Comment: an instruction that uses `xmm` registers is necessarily an SIMD instruction? I find that `movsd` uses `xmm` but is not in SIMD list [link](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/inst-ref-simd.html)